# simple javascript pagination for <li><a href

Tags: javascript, pagination

I'm trying to make a simple (only next previous buttons) javascript pagination for my `<li>` links.
this is my link list :

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="listingTable">
        <ul id = "Mylinks" class="paging">
            <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://site1.com" rel="nofollow">Description1</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://site2.com" rel="nofollow">Description2</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://site3.com" rel="nofollow">Description3</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://site4.com" rel="nofollow">Description4</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://site5.com" rel="nofollow">Description5</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://site6.com" rel="nofollow">Description6</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://site7.com" rel="nofollow">Description7</a></li>
            <li style="display: none;"><a href="http://site100.com" rel="nofollow">Description100</a></li>
            //Number of links is unlimited.
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="pager">
      <li><a href="javascript:prevPage()" id="btn_prev">previous</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:nextPage()" id="btn_next">next</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm Using bootstrap css.
I don't want to use jquery.
my code is nearly working.

```
 var current_page = 1;
    var records_per_page = 3;

    function prevPage()
    {
        if (current_page > 1) {
            current_page--;
            changePage(current_page);
        }
    }

    function nextPage()
    {
        if (current_page < numPages()) {
            current_page++;
            changePage(current_page);
        }
    }

    function changePage(page)
    {
        var btn_next = document.getElementById("btn_next");
        var btn_prev = document.getElementById("btn_prev");
        var listing_table = document.getElementById("listingTable");
        var page_span = document.getElementById("page");

        // Validate page
        if (page < 1) page = 1;
        if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();

var list = document.getElementById('linkbox'),items = list.childNodes;
    for (var i = (page-1) * records_per_page; i < (page * records_per_page) && i < childNodes.length; i++) {
        items[i].style.display = "block";
    }
        }
        page_span.innerHTML = page + "/" + numPages();

        if (page == 1) {
            btn_prev.style.visibility = "hidden";
        } else {
            btn_prev.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        if (page == numPages()) {
            btn_next.style.visibility = "hidden";
        } else {
            btn_next.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }

    function numPages()
    {
        return Math.ceil(objJson.length / records_per_page);
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        changePage(1);
    };
```

But the problem is `var objJson = []`
I want to use `style="display: block;"` for page1 and put `style="display: none;"` for rest of links. when page changes style changes too.

**Updated:**

I put my links Directly inside `<ul>` I think it is not good Idea to put them in java script and show only parts of them, Difference is :
google consider all links inside `<ul></ul>` but when I put them in javascript only page1 is in `<ul></ul>`.
I should get all links by :

```
var list = document.getElementById('Mylinks'),
    items = list.childNodes;

for (var i = 0, length = childNodes.length; i < length; i++)
{
    if (items[i].nodeType != 1) {
       continue;
    }
    items[i].style.display = "block"; 
}
```

and update styles for page 1 to `style="display: block;"`

Comment: Your links (`<li><a href="http://site1.com" rel="nofollow">Description1</a></li>`) are created dynamically with your `objJson` ?

Comment: dynamically but with php, directly inside `<ul class="paging"></ul>`  I think i should delete `var objJson = []` and change code inside. @SteevePitis

Comment: Arf I've done something with objJson. Try to do the same with php and remove my `initPages`

Answer (score 0):

If I have understanding what you want, it will be easier to say a `<ul>` represent one page.

According to this you can do something like this :

```js
var current_page = 1;
var records_per_page = 3;

var objJson = [
    { adName: "AdName 1"},
    { adName: "AdName 2"},
    { adName: "AdName 3"},
    { adName: "AdName 4"},
    { adName: "AdName 5"},
    { adName: "AdName 6"},
    { adName: "AdName 7"},
    { adName: "AdName 8"},
    { adName: "AdName 9"},
    { adName: "AdName 10"}
]; // Can be obtained from another source, such as your objJson variable

function prevPage()
{
    if (current_page > 1) {
        current_page--;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}

function nextPage()
{
    if (current_page < numPages()) {
        current_page++;
        changePage(current_page);
    }
}

function changePage(page)
{
    var btn_next = document.getElementById("btn_next");
    var btn_prev = document.getElementById("btn_prev");
    var page_span = document.getElementById("page");

    // Validate page
    if (page < 1) page = 1;
    if (page > numPages()) page = numPages();

    if(document.querySelector('.current')) document.querySelector('.current').classList.remove('current');
    document.getElementById('page'+page).classList.add('current')
    
    page_span.innerHTML = page + "/" + numPages();

    if (page == 1) {
        btn_prev.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        btn_prev.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    if (page == numPages()) {
        btn_next.style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        btn_next.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}

function numPages()
{
    return Math.ceil(objJson.length / records_per_page);
}

function initPages() {
  var ul;
  var container = document.getElementById("listingTable");
  for(var i = 0; i<objJson.length; i++) {
    if(i%records_per_page === 0){
      ul = document.createElement('ul');
      ul.className = "paging";
      ul.id = "page"+ ((i/records_per_page)+1);
      container.appendChild(ul);
    }
    
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = '#';
    a.innerHTML = objJson[i].adName;
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  changePage(1);
}

window.onload = function() {
    initPages();
    
};
```

```css
.paging {
  display: none; 
}

.paging.current{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="listingTable">
    </div>
    <ul class="pager">
      <li><a href="javascript:prevPage()" id="btn_prev">قبلی</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:nextPage()" id="btn_next">بعدی</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<span id="page"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But I want to put my links directly inside html. I dont want to put them inside javascript `var objJson = []` google consider links inside <ul> when I put them in javascript only parts of them that are in html are considered. I'm going to Delete `var objJson = []` Completely and use `var list = document.getElementById('list_name'),
    items = list.childNodes;

for (var i = 0, length = childNodes.length; i < length; i++)
{
    if (items[i].nodeType != 1) {
       continue;
    }
    items[i].innerHTML = "<a>text</a>"; 
}` For finding <li> and only show page 1

Comment: Then with your php , you just have to follow the same structure that I've created `<ul class='paging' id='page1'><li ... /></ul>`, remove my `initPages()` and this code will continue to work.

Comment: Please see Updated Question! @Steeve Pitis

Comment: Can you check why `items[i].style.display = "block";` not work? I rewite all codes above @Steeve Pitis

Comment: `var items = document.querySelectorAll('#Mylinks li');

for (var i = 0, length = item.length; i < length; i++)
{
    items[i].style.display = "block"; 
}` try with this